# Flask test client using GET request instead of POST

Tags: python, flask, flask-testing

I have a route for only POST request and it returns json response if conditions are met. It's something like this:

```
@app.route('/panel', methods=['POST'])
def post_panel():
    # Check for conditions and database operations
    return jsonify({"message": "Panel added to database!"
                    "success": 1})
```

I am using [flask-sslify](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify) to force http requests to https.

I am testing this route with Flask test client and unittest. The test function is similar to following:

```
class TestAPI2_0(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
    self.app = create_app('testing')
    self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
    self.app_context.push()
    db.create_all()
    create_fake_data(db)
    self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def tearDown(self):
        ....

    def test_post_panel_with_good_data(self):    
        # data
        r = self.client.post('/panel',
                            data=json.dumps(data),
                            follow_redirects=True)  
        print(r.data)      
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
```

Output is exactly below:

```
test_post_panel_with_good_data (tests.test_api_2_0.TestAPI2_0) ... b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>\n<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>\n<p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>\n'


======================================================================
FAIL: test_post_panel_with_good_data (tests.test_api_2_0.TestAPI2_0)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tanjibpa/work/craftr-master/tests/test_api_2_0.py", line 110, in test_post_panel_with_good_data
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 405 != 200
```

I am getting an error that Method is not allowed in that route. 
If I specify GET as a method (`methods=['GET', 'POST']`) for the route test seems to work. But why test client is making a GET request? Is there any way around rather than specifying a GET request for the route?

**Update:**

If do it like this:

```
@app.route('/panel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_panel():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Check for conditions and database operations
        return jsonify({"message": "Panel added to database!"
                        "success": 1})
    return jsonify({"message": "GET request"})
```

I get output like this:

```
test_post_panel_with_good_data (tests.test_api_2_0.TestAPI2_0) ... b'{\n  "message": "GET request"\n}\n'
```

Comment: In the code I see a route defined as `/panel`, and in the test method a call to `/api/panel`. Is that right like that?

Comment: Yes. That's right. It's because of the api blueprint's route prefix.

Comment: Could you try using `url_for(api.post_panel)`? Maybe your routes aren't what you think they are

Comment: @RyanBaker Have tried `url_for()`. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was causing the GET request within flask test client. 
I am using flask-sslify to force http requests to https.
Somehow flask-sslify is enforcing a GET request although test client is specified with other kind of requests (POST, PUT, DELETE...).

So, If I disable sslify during testing flask test client works as it should.

Comment: Thanks! Please explain how to disable sslify? I dont use sslify but maybe flask_talisman or one of those other security things are creating the same issue..

Comment: I never would have guessed it was flask-sslify... that fixed the issue for me. I was unable to POST at all with the Flask test_client (but all GET requests worked fine). Now the test_client works for POST and GET after removing _ = SSLify(app). Also setting app.debug = True when declaring the test_client also seems to fix it for me